# Monkey runner script for delayed clicks

Tags: android, simulation, monkeyrunner

I am completely new to monkeyrunner but I need a script. I know it is simple to be donned but for inexperienced person in that area I will need hours of trying to make it work.

So can someone give me a script that will send 3 click to 100,100 coordinate but this clicks to be delayed for a 5 seconds period

something like this

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

//first simulate home click
//sleep 3 seconds
//click at 100,100 coordinates
//sleep 3 seconds
//click at 100,100 coordinates
//sleep 3 seconds
//click at 100,100 coordinates
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example (without any check of result)

```
# click home button
result = device.press("KEYCODE_HOME", "DOWN_AND_UP", "")

# sleep 3 seconds
MonkeyRunner.sleep(3.0)

# click at 100,100 coordinates
result = device.touch(100, 100, "DOWN_AND_UP")
```

Comment: what value the result contains ?